# Android web automation in app

Tags: android, selenium, web-testing

I would like to make a simple android app that can perform some automated behaviour on the web.

I want to be able to input username/password details and gave my app navigate to a website via a web view presumably and fill in my login credentials and navigate to a particular section of the website.

I realise selenium would be ideal for a task like this but was wondering if anyone had experience of trying something similar and whether it is all possible from inside the Android app rather than running on a standalone server testing the actual app as I realise is selenium/selenedroids main purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to automate the actions for testing of your web from an Android app, try [calabash-android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/), it's like Selenium for Android.

Calabash-android supports `WebView` manipulation, in your case entering text as well.

> You can use the enter_text method to enter text in a webview (in addition to any other android widget).
>
> `enter_text("webView css:'input.login'", "run")`
>
> This will enter the text "run" into the first input field of the class 'login'.

Source: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/06-webview-support

Comment: Thanks hidro, very helpful I'll check out the calabash-android library looks like it could be just what I'm looking for.